# hreflang tags implementation not reflecting in Google Search results

Tags: search-engine-indexing, local-seo, hreflang, technical-seo

My website homepage has 3 versions: one for India (`unitedwecare.test/in`), one for Canada (`unitedwecare.test/ca`) and one for rest of world (`unitedwecare.test/`). All the rest of the pages are the same. I'm using `hreflang` tags, so I want `unitedwecare.test/in` to appear as the main result when people search `google.co.in` for 'united we care'. However, still `unitedwecare.test` is being shown as the first result.

Here's the code I've implemented on all three versions of the homepage, i.e. `unitedwecare.test/in`, `unitedwecare.test/ca` and `unitedwecare.test/`, along with their respective canonical tags for each version.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.unitedwecare.test/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ca" href="https://www.unitedwecare.test/ca" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-in" href="https://www.unitedwecare.test/in" />
```

I've also tried replacing `unitedwecare.test/` with `unitedwecare.test/en` (since the homepage is located at `/en` at the backend), but to no avail.

I only want to implement `hreflang` only on the homepage. What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any help.

Comment: How are you testing this?  Are you having somebody who is in India do the search or are you doing the search from outside of India?   Google uses your location, not just which search engine you use to determine which results to show you.

Comment: the user is redirected based on his/her ip address

Comment: I'm doing the search from India, still hreflang isn't being implemented